# Maximum of a function.

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Let $H:R^n \to R$ be $C^2(R^n\setminus\{0\})$ if $H(x) \neq 0$ and $H(0)=0$, strictly convex function and homogeneous of degree 2. 
Define $G(y)= \max_{x \in R^n} ( \langle x,y \rangle - H(x))$.

So, $G(y)$ is well defined, this Is, for fixed $y$, $ x \mapsto  \langle x,y \rangle - H(x)$ has a unique maximum.

I know that this followns from the strictly convex hypothesis and the fact that for some $c>0$ we have 
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{c} \langle y,y \rangle \leq H(y) \leq c \langle y,y \rangle, \; \forall y\neq 0.
\end{equation}

And that, if $x_0$ is a maximum so $x_0$ must obey $ y= \nabla H (x_0)$.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: To confirm, are you trying to show $x \mapsto \langle x, y \rangle - H(x)$ obtains a unique maximum for any given $y$, where $H$ is strictly convex, homogeneous of degree $2$, and continuously twice-differentiable everywhere but $0$?

Comment: Hi Theo Bendit, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a unique maximum is achieved, and only strict convexity is necessary for this.

Fix $y \in \Bbb{R}^n$ and suppose $x_1, x_2$ both maximise the problem. That is,
$$\langle x_1, y \rangle - H(x_1) = \langle x_2, y \rangle - H(x_2) = G(y).$$
Let $x = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}$. Then,
$$\langle x, y \rangle - H(x) \le G(y) = \langle x_1, y \rangle - H(x_1).$$
By strict convexity, we must have
$$H(x) < \frac{H(x_1) + H(x_2)}{2},$$
hence
\begin{align*}
\langle x_1, y \rangle - H(x_1) &\ge \langle x, y \rangle - H(x) \\
&> \frac{\langle x_1, y \rangle + \langle x_2, y \rangle}{2} - \frac{H(x_1) + H(x_2)}{2} \\
&= \frac{(\langle x_1, y\rangle - H(x_1)) + (\langle x_2, y\rangle - H(x_2))}{2} \\
&= \frac{G(y) + G(y)}{2} = G(y).
\end{align*}
This contradicts the definition of $G(y)$.